# Can "ĵus" be used with the present tense?

Tags: word-usage

A discussion started regarding this in the comments of a different post:

[How to say "I don't feel like it" in Esperanto](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/969/how-to-say-i-dont-feel-like-it-in-esperanto)

The example used was "ĵus nun mi ne emas".

I think it is relevant enough to be asked seperately.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is only possible in sentences like *Mi kutime vizitas ĵus antaŭ Kristnasko.* The *ĵus* is attached to *Kristnasko* rather than the verb.

Sometimes people use *ĵus* to refer to location, e.g. *Ĝi situas ĵus antaŭ la pordego*, but this is generally considered wrong *("ĝuste antaŭ...")*

Otherwise, if the action is continuing, you have to say *de ĵus*.

- *Mi ĵus komencis. Mi de ĵus komencas.*
- *Kiam li eniros, mi estos ĵus komencinta paroli.*

I am uncertain about the correctness of *Kiam li eniros, mi de ĵus komencos paroli.*

The words *ĵus—tuj* can be considered a pair of opposites. *Ĵus* refers to a moment before, *tuj* to a moment after. However, *tuj* can also mean *senprokraste* or *proksimege*, and thus used with any tense.

Answer (score 10):

PMEG has a quite clear [recommendation](http://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/e-vortecaj_vortetoj/tempaj/jhus.html) against doing this:

> Kelkaj uzas *ĵus* en la signifo “precize en la nuna momento, precize en tiu momento”. Tio estas eraro. *Ĵus* ĉiam almontras la pasintecon, momenton antaŭan. Ne eblas diri: **Li ĵus venas.** Necesas diri: *Li ĝuste nun* (*precize nun*, *ekzakte nun*...) *venas*. Iuj uzas *ĵus* en la signifo “precize, ĝuste” eĉ kiam tute ne temas pri tempo. Ankaŭ tio estas eraro. *Ĵus* ĉiam estas tempa vorteto. Ne eblas diri: **Mi havas ĵus tiom da mono, kiom mi bezonas.**

Quick translation:

> Several people use *ĵus* in the sense of “precisely in the current moment, precisely in that moment”. That is an error. *Ĵus* always shows the past, a previous moment. It's not possible to say: **Li ĵus venas**. You have to say: *Li ĝuste nun (precize nun, ekzakte nun…) venas*. Some people use *ĵus* to mean “precisely” even when it's not about time at all. That is also an error. *Ĵus* is always a temporal word. It's not possible to say: **Mi havas ĵus tiom da mono, kiom mi bezonas**.

I think this matches the [definition given in PIV:](http://vortaro.net/#%C4%B5us)

> Cirkonstanca morfemo, signifanta «momenton antaŭ nun» aŭ «antaŭ tiam»

Rough translation:

> Circumstantial morpheme, meaning “a moment before now” or “before then”

If we accept that definition then *ĵus nun* is an oxymoron.

Answer (score 2):

I just checked [PMEG](http://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/e-vortecaj_vortetoj/tempaj/jhus.html). It indeed says it can't. Yet I don't see why. The *Fundamento* does not imply it according to my perception.

I will discuss this with Bertilo, when I see him next time. It would be interesting to know why he so clearly says, that it's an error.